# Save button not working in layer slider

Tags: slider, wordpress

i am using vanguard theme layer slider for my homepage, but in the dashboard when i edit a layer slider and click on save button it remains the red one means doesn't proceed to saved it  stop on saving. please help me out for that. i can not change my slides without resolving that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a .htaccess file in your /wp-admin/ directory with this contents:

```
    <IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

If that doesn't work contact your hosting provider.
Yes, it seems to be a server issue, most likely a misconfigured htaccess or something like that which blocks the AJAX requests.

See this thread for more info
[support thread from plugin provider](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246/comments?filter=All%20Discussion&page=118#comment_3689591)

Answer (score 0):

(Apache)
If you have server acces try adding the following to /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/example.com/wp-admin">
   <IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleEngine Off
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```